# Make PHP pathinfo() return the correct filename if the filename is UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, pathinfo

When using PHP's `pathinfo()` function on a filename known to be UTF-8, it does not return the correct value, unless there are 'normal' characters in front of the special character.

Examples:
`pathinfo('aä.pdf')`returns:

```
Array
(
[dirname] => [the dir]
[basename] => aä.pdf
[extension] => pdf
[filename] => aä
)
```

which is fine and dandy, but `pathinfo('äa.pdf')`returns:

```
Array
(
[dirname] => [the dir]
[basename] => a.pdf
[extension] => pdf
[filename] => a
)
```

Which is not quite what I was expecting. Even worse, `pathinfo('ä.pdf')`returns:

```
Array
(
[dirname] => [the dir]
[basename] => .pdf
[extension] => pdf
[filename] => 
)
```

Why does it do this? This goes for all accented characters I have tested.

Comment: Most core PHP functions don't deal with character sets other than ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1).  You're only real option is to re-implement the function yourself using multi-byte charset safe functions (`mb_string` functions)

Comment: which version of PHP are you running ?

Comment: @ajreal it's PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny9 on debian lenny

Comment: When printing to screen or the terminal are you using a terminal that supports UTF-8? And when printing to screen (browser?) is the encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes to both :) Actually the documentation is now updated to reflect that pathinfo() is locale aware. I am still unsure how or what happens, the workaround I posted still works (as expected), but I strongly suspect it was the server's locale messing things up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A temporary work-around for this problem appears to be to make sure there is a 'normal' character in front of the accented characters, like so:

```
function getFilename($path)
{
    // if there's no '/', we're probably dealing with just a filename
    // so just put an 'a' in front of it
    if (strpos($path, '/') === false)
    {
        $path_parts = pathinfo('a'.$path);
    }
    else
    {
        $path= str_replace('/', '/a', $path);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    }
    return substr($path_parts["filename"],1);
}
```

Note that we replace all occurrences of '/' with '/a' but this is okay, since we return starting at offset 1 of the result. Interestingly enough, the `dirname` part of `pathinfo()` does seem to work, so no workaround is needed there.

Comment: This is still a bug in 2016, but  `setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8');` works.

Answer (score 18):

before usage pathinfo

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8');
pathinfo($OriginalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
pathinfo($OriginalName, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you are adding some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.

Comment: This answer helped and it is simple. Please add more explanation to enhance its value to others.

Comment: There in an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268499/php-basename-and-pathinfo-with-multibytes-utf-8-file-names/45268539#45268539

Answer (score 10):

I have used these functions in PHP 5.3.3 - 5.3.18 to handle UTF-8 issue in basename() and pathinfo().

```
if (!function_exists("mb_basename"))
{
  function mb_basename($path)
  {
    $separator = " qq ";
    $path = preg_replace("/[^ ]/u", $separator."\$0".$separator, $path);
    $base = basename($path);
    $base = str_replace($separator, "", $base);
    return $base;
  }
}
```

```
if (!function_exists("mb_pathinfo"))
{
  function mb_pathinfo($path, $opt = "")
  {
    $separator = " qq ";
    $path = preg_replace("/[^ ]/u", $separator."\$0".$separator, $path);
    if ($opt == "") $pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
    else $pathinfo = pathinfo($path, $opt);

    if (is_array($pathinfo))
    {
      $pathinfo2 = $pathinfo;
      foreach($pathinfo2 as $key => $val)
      {
        $pathinfo[$key] = str_replace($separator, "", $val);
      }
    }
    else if (is_string($pathinfo)) $pathinfo = str_replace($separator, "", $pathinfo);
    return $pathinfo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to "[pathinfo() cannot handle argument with special characters like german 'Umlaute'](http://bugs.php.net/37945)".

Comment: That bug is relating to non-ascii characters, not UTF-8 characters.  So I'm not sure if it's 100% applicable (it may be, so no -1, but it's also a very old bug, so I'm fairly sure it's not the root cause)...

Comment: @ircmaxell My characters indeed are (or at the very least should be) UTF-8. That is: my locale is UTF-8 and the .php file is saved as UTF-8. I think I will rewrite the function using pathinfo() to use my own logic, but it is kind of 'meh'.

Answer (score 1):

When process ansi characters, the function pathinfo do correctly.

Base this note, we will convert (encoding) input to ansi charaters and then still use function pathinfo to keep its whole things.

Finally, we will convert (decoding) output values to original format.

And demo as bellowing.

```
function _pathinfo($path, $options = null)
{
    $path = urlencode($path);
    $parts = null === $options ? pathinfo($path) : pathinfo($path, $options);
    foreach ($parts as $field => $value) {
        $parts[$field] = urldecode($value);
    }
    return $parts;
}
// calling
_pathinfo('すtest.jpg');
_pathinfo('すtest.jpg', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function _pathinfo($path, $options = null) {
  $result = pathinfo(' ' . $path, $options);
  return substr($result, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) shows,

> Caution
>
> pathinfo() is locale aware, so for it to parse a path containing
>   multibyte characters correctly, the matching locale must be set using
>   the setlocale() function.

and the [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#119468) in the manual