# basename() fail when file name start by an accent

Tags: php, filenames

Here is a quick example to show the issue:

```
print basename('léquipe.jpg'); // léquipe.jpg
print basename('équipe.jpg');  // quipe.jpg
```

How can I avoid this inconsistency, and be sure that `basename()` will return me the whole file name?

Thanks

Comment: what encoding are you using?

Comment: I think you should look at your php.ini and add `mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8`

Comment: CHeck this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451664/make-php-pathinfo-return-the-correct-filename-if-the-filename-is-utf-8)

Comment: In order to 'avoid' you could simply prepend an ascii character ('a').

Comment: I use utf8 everywhere, so it **should** be the same, but I'm not aware of the exact `<input type="file">` machinery.

Comment: @zessx Let me guess: `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` prints: `9223372036854775807` means you have a 64 bit installation, *right* ?

Comment: @zessx I try the code `print basename('équipe.jpg');` in my mac and it out `équipe.jpg`
that will be there some other reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as it turns out this seems to be a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62119

If the first character is a non-ASCII character the character just disappears. If there are non-ASCII characters in the path itself it works fine.

Also what seems to be strange is that this problem only occurse for 64-bit PHP installations:

- [64bit version](http://viper-7.com/jGWvhX) (doesn't work as expected)
- [32bit version](https://eval.in/419544) (works as expected)

To solve this you could use a custom function as provided from a [PHP manual comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php#85369):

```
function mb_basename($file) 
{ 
    return end(explode('/',$file)); 
}
```

<sub>Code from: "(remove) dot nasretdinov at (remove) dot gmail dot com"</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php to solve this problem.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_FR.utf8');

print basename('léquipe.jpg'); // léquipe.jpg
print basename('équipe.jpg');  // équipe.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for windows server replace '/'):

```
function mb_basename($file)
{
  $temp = explode('/', $file);
  return end($temp);
}
print mb_basename('léquipe.jpg'); // léquipe.jpg
print mb_basename('équipe.jpg');  // équipe.jpg
```

Comment: Want to give them at least the credits: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php#85369 ? (Also what is the reason for this happening ?)

Comment: Sorry that doesn't give link to source page.
It happens because functions basename and pathinfo can't work with filenames in UTF

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a little change to avoid errors (in my case):

```
function _basename($file){
    $array=explode('/',$file);
    if (is_array($array)){
        return end($array);
    }else{
        return $file;
    }
}
```

enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !function_exists( "mb_basename")){
    function mb_basename( $file, $ext){
        $file = explode( '/', $file);
        $file = end( $file);
        if( $ext){
            $p = strripos( $file, $ext);
            if( $p !== false && $p == strlen( $file) -strlen( $ext))$file = substr( $file, 0, $p);
        }
        return $file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this proposal handles suffix parameter, and a test list. Be aware of trailing '/' behaviour.

Tests output:

```
________________________________________________________
‾‾ basename ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
0) sudoers
1) sudoers.d
2) passwd
3) etc
4) .
5) 
6) ..
7) lément
8) lément.txt
9) lément.TXT
10) lément.jpg
11) quipe
12) quipe
________________________________________________________
‾‾ mb_basename ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
0) sudoers
1) sudoers.d
2) passwd
3) etc
4) .
5) 
6) ..
7) élément
8) élément.txt
9) élément.TXT
10) élément.jpg
11) équipe
12) équipe
```

Source code:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists ( 'mb_basename' ) ) {
    function mb_basename ( $path, $suffix='' ) {
        $array = explode ( '/', rtrim( $path, '/' ) ) ;
        $basename = end ( $array ) ;
        if( ! empty ( $suffix ) ) {
            $slen = strlen ( $suffix ) ;
            if ( substr ( $basename, -$slen, $slen) == $suffix ) {
                $basename = substr ( $basename, 0, -$slen ) ;
            }
        }
        return $basename;
    }
}

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php#example-2871
$tests = array (
    array ( '/etc/sudoers.d', '.d' ),
    array ( '/etc/sudoers.d' ),
    array ( '/etc/passwd' ),
    array ( '/etc/' ),
    array ( '.' ),
    array ( '/' ),
    array ( '..' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe/élément.txt', '.txt' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe/élément.txt', '.TXT' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe/élément.TXT', '.txt' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe/élément.jpg', '.txt' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe/' ),
    array ( '/home/user/équipe' ),
);
echo '________________________________________________________'.PHP_EOL ;
echo '‾‾ basename ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾'.PHP_EOL ;
foreach ( $tests as $key => $test ) {
    echo $key .') '. basename ( $test[0], @$test[1] ) .PHP_EOL ;
}
echo '________________________________________________________'.PHP_EOL ;
echo '‾‾ mb_basename ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾'.PHP_EOL ;
foreach ( $tests as $key => $test ) {
    echo $key .') '. mb_basename ( $test[0], @$test[1] ) .PHP_EOL ;
}
?>
```