# PHP indexing files with special characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to organize my music collection using PHP and MySQL. I'm using php to list all the files in my music-directory, and store this information in a MySQL database. For most files it works fine, but some filenames end up like this:

**Current situation:**
Mai^tre Gims - J'me tire.mp3
Tie¨sto - Red lights.mp3
Ma°ns Zelmerlo¨w - Heroes.mp3

I believe these are called "combining characters", characters intended to modify other characters.

Obviously I want the characters to be combined:

**Wanted situation:**
Maître Gims - J'me tire.mp3
Tiësto - Red lights.mp3
Måns Zelmerlöw - Heroes.mp3

This is the testcode I'm using:

```
$path = 'D:\Music';

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    $filename = utf8_encode($fileInfo->getFilename());
    echo $filename . "<br>\n";
}
```

Without utf8_encode() I get questionmarks: �
The header in my webpage is set to UTF-8.

I've tried different functions like **iconv()** and **mb_convert_encoding()** but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how I can get from the **current** to the **wanted** filenames?

Comment: what do the filenames actually look like : _mai^tre_ or _maître_ ?...

Comment: Filenames look like _maître_, so they look right. However, they may have been typed like _mai^tre_ when the filename was given.

Comment: ...no, they may have been type _ma^itre_, not _mai^tre_...

Comment: you may want to have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451664/make-php-pathinfo-return-the-correct-filename-if-the-filename-is-utf-8) (if not already done) !