# PHPmailer arabic attachment name issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use `dompdf` to generate a PDF file, Then I send it using `PHPmailer`. But the issue is that the file name of the generated PDF name is not correct.

Here is the code:

```
//PDF from dompdf
$pdf = $dompdf->output();

//PHPmailer confiurgation
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';  

//PDF name
$name = 'محمد احمد علي';
$pdfName = str_replace(" ", "_", $name); //Replace spaces with _
$pdfName .= ".pdf";

//Attach PDF
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, $pdfName);
```

The PDf name should be `محمد_احمد_علي.pdf` in this case. But it's `_احمد_علي.pdf`

I tried:

```
$encoding = 'base64';
$type = 'application/pdf';
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, $pdfName, $encoding, $type);
```

Also:

```
$mail->Encoding = "base64";
```

But no success.

I don't see that there is an issue with the string name, As when I run the following code:

```
$name = 'محمد علي احمد';
$name = str_replace(' ', "_", $name);
echo $name . '.pdf';
```

I get the expected result.

How to solve this issue?

**Update**

I just tried:

```
$dompdf->stream($filename);
```

To download the PDF without sending it. And it's the same result, So I don't know where the issue is coming from.

**New Update**
In case this happens to anyone in the future.

I found out why this is happening. `Dompdf` is using `basename()` on the file name. And with my Arabic name that function makes it go wrong like that.

It's really sad how programming languages and libraries are ignoring RTL languages like Arabic.

So running this code:

```
echo basename('محمد احمد علي');
```

Would return `احمد علي`

Comment: I just tested this and found that the attachment name came out correctly. Are you running the latest version of PHPMailer?

Comment: @Synchro, Yeah. How did you generate the attacheded file?

Comment: I found out why this is happening. It's from `Dompdf` not PHPmailer

Comment: It doesn't matter how you make the attached file or data; PHPMailer doesn't care what is in it. You don't need to set the encoding or MIME type if the file extension is a known one (which `.pdf` is).

Comment: OK, should probably close this then, unless you can link it to a known dompdf bug.

Comment: @Synchro, I found out what is causing the issue. Not the solution

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: There is talk of changing the locale, could you try that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268539/231316

Comment: Does the comment about locales in [the PHP docs on the `basename` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) apply to you?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I tried it. But didn't work

Comment: This one worked for me `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`. Not sure if it's the best option